# How to get all the posts in a Facebook group without a limit.? It only returns 25..?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have used the call

`GroupId?fields=feed{full_picture,place,from,comments{message},message,likes.limit(0).summary(true)}`

to get the stated data for my application. But this only returns 25 feeds/posts. I also tried and limit number `&limit=number (number like 1000)` appending to the above. Yet it returns only 25. How to get all the posts?

Answer (score 0):

Search for "Traversing Paged Results" in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_pagination_basic

Some API calls have a max limit, so paging would be the only reliable way to get all items.